# How to make text style like groupon app without using webview?

Tags: ios, iphone

Can anybody tell me how to use groupon like text formatting while showing the details of any item without using webview?

Comment: Hi, You can create your customView with help of UIScrollVie, UILabel for that.

Comment: What do u mean by "groupon like text formatting". Give some link or image.

Comment: Hi CRDave, Please install groupon app on your device. Then see the detail of any item. The detail page is very nicely formatted. They are    using webview. But I need to do this using simple UILabel and other native controls. I need to parse the html with css and show relevent data on Label or TextView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this..

- NSMutableAttributedString
- NSAttributedString

UITextView *textView; (Your Text View)
textView.attributedText = (NSAttributedString created by you)

To know more about Attributed String

http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/format-text-in-ios6-attributed-strings